How to Add For Loop Inside SafeArea in Flet?
How to add for loop inside SafeArea in Flet? I want to add for loop inside SafeArea.
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(
        ft.SafeArea(
        
        )
    )
    for i in range(50):
        page.controls.append(ft.Text(f"Line {i}"))
    page.scroll = "always"
    page.update()

ft.app(main)


I have no idea what flet is, but you can't do that literally. The () is an argument list which can only contain expressions, and a for is a statement. You'd need to use a comprehension, or loop over the call to SafeArea. You may need to give more detail about what you're trying to do.

The SafeArea will take a list of components. Just ass this as a list comprehension, like:
ft.SafeArea(
        [ft.Text(f"Line {i}") for i in range(50)]
)


I don't know what exactly you wanna achive, but if you want to add controls inside SafeArea first you need to set content of SafeArea for exemple let it be ft.Column named my_column then set my_column as SafeArea content and then use your loop to and controls to my_column. Now every control putted inside my_column is inside SafeArea.
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):

    my_column = ft.Column([])
    page.add(
        ft.SafeArea(my_column)
    )
    for i in range(50):
        my_column.controls.append(ft.Text(f"Line {i}"))
    page.scroll = "always"
    page.update()


ft.app(main)

If you want make it shorter you can do it like this
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):

    page.add(
        ft.SafeArea(ft.Column([ft.Text(f"Line {i}") for i in range(50)]))
    )
    
    page.scroll = "always"
    page.update()


ft.app(main)


This gives error: SafeArea.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'content'

I don't get any error in this code, but you can try replace in first way ft.SafeArea(my_column) with ft.SafeArea(content=my_column),
